# Getting Issues in IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, joomla1.5

Everything is working fine but as i moved my website in IE, the content is not displaying-- I am using IE 8.0. URL is

http://skjeeelectricals.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=59

Kindly help me out from this kind of issue.

Thanks
JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your code [valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://skjeeelectricals.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=59&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) (fix validation errors) and you will be fine.